# bind data for axios onUploadProgress in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am new to Vuejs . Please help me .
This is my LevelApi class for handle CRUD operations for Level object in my database . the create function of this class gets the form data and post it to the Node js Api and then returns the response . In my AddLevel component when the user submits the form , I call this method and pass the form data that contains one file to be uploaded to the Level collection in mongodb .

```
import axios from 'axios'
const API_URL = 'http://example:8080/api/level/'

export default class LevelApi {

  create (formData) {
   return axios.post('http://example.com/api/level/', formData, {

      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt'), 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total))
      }.bind(this)

    })
 }
```

And below is my AddLevel component .

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>please choose image for this level</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" ref="myFiles" @change="previewFiles">
      </div>

      <button @click.prevent="storeLevel">add level</button>

    </form>
        <progress-bar v-bind:val="getPercentage" max="100" :text="uploadPercentageWithPercent"></progress-bar>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import LevelApi from '../../services/api/level/LevelApi' // importing the LevelApi class that I mentioned above

  const levelApi = new LevelApi()

  export default {
    name: 'AddLevel',
    data () {
      return {
        files: {},
        uploadPercentage: 0,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      storeLevel () {

        var formData = new FormData()

        formData.append('file', this.files)

         levelApi.create(formData).then((response)=>{

            console.log(response.data)

         });

      },
      previewFiles () {
        this.files = this.$refs.myFiles.files[0]
      },
    },
    computed: {

      uploadPercentageWithPercent () {
        return this.uploadPercentage.toString().concat('%')
      },
      getPercentage () {
        return this.uploadPercentage
      },
      resetPercentage () {
        this.uploadPercentage = 0
      }

    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style
```

Everything is ok and the file uploads but the progress bar does not show the uploadPercentage data . but when I console log this uploadPercentage it grows up to 100% . I changed my code to below and the problem solved . the below code does not use ApiLevel class now . now the progress bar shows the percent of the upload . Whats the problem with my ApiLevel class . Why progress bar does not show the upload percent although uploadPercentage value changes in the console.log function .

```
var formData = new FormData()

    formData.append('file', this.files)

    this.$http.post('http://example.com/api/level/', formData, {

      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt'), 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        this.uploadPercentage = parseInt(Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total))
      }.bind(this)

    }).then((response) => {

      }

    })
```

Comment: did you get errors when you tried the first approach ?

Comment: No . Its all ok